# How to register Qt C++ object to use it in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I try to register ColorsSource *pSource object to use it in QML but I get erreor in string: 
"QQmlContext *context = myObject->rootContext();"
undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK12QQuickWidget11rootContextEv`

main.cpp

```
#include "ColorsSource.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQuickWidgets/QQuickWidget>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.load(url);

    ColorsSource *pSource = new ColorsSource;

    QQuickWidget *myObject = static_cast<QQuickWidget*>(engine.rootObjects().first());

    QQmlContext *context = myObject->rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("ColorSource", pSource);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `quickwidgets` Qt module. Thats why it cannot find these Symbols. If you use qmake, add `QT += quickwidgets` to your pro file.

But that won't be your Problem. QQuickWidgets are widgets to display some QQuick code, to be used in a Widgets application. But as you use a QQmlApplicationEngine, you are working in Quick. Your `rootObject()` won't be a QQuickWidget. So instead of looking for a QQuickWidget, access the engines rootContext - replace:

```
QQuickWidget *myObject = static_cast<QQuickWidget*>(engine.rootObjects().first());
QQmlContext *context = myObject->rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("ColorSource", pSource);
```

with

```
QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("ColorSource", pSource);
```

This will make your code a lot less prone to errors.

Also, in an unrelated note, you should always check your pointers, to make sure your `static_cast` went allright. Otherwise you will get crashes if the engines rootObjects are empty or the first one is not a QQuickWidget.

Comment: I use CMake instead of qmake

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин - [Similar procedure](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-variable-reference.html#module-variables) but again, you will not need the quickwidgets module if you are using the QQmlApplicationContext. Strip all the QQuickWidget includes and replace the stuff I wrote in my answer, this should fix things for you

Comment: Thanks it helped me, engine.rootContext() is really works

Comment: Good to hear. As a tip: Have a look into the differences between a QWidget based application and a QQuick based application. These are two entirely different concepts and understanding what you are working with makes a huge difference in your development.